# Maximum force during a collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, stress-strain

When 2 bodies collide with each other, they deform for a while. The contact force rises, reaches a maximum, then falls. It is easy to find the average force during this time if we know the duration of collision and the change in momentum. But how should we find out the maximum force that is exerted between the 2 objects? What parameters should we consider while trying to do so?

For simplicity I tried taking 2 cubes of same dimensions of masses $m_1, m_2$ colliding head on with velocities $v_1, v_2$. In an elastic collision, I am assuming the total energy will remain same (kinetic + deformation energies). The force will be maximum when they move with same velocity $v' = \frac{m_1 v_1 - m_2 v_2}{m_1 + m_2} $.

At this moment, if we take the contact force to be F, then the stress in the cubes will decrease linearly away from the plane of contact  = $Fx\over lA$ where x is distance from contact plane, A is cross sectional area and l is length of cube. The strain energy stored in element dx with area A, at distance x from the plane will be $\frac{1}{2Y} * (\frac{Fx}{lA})^2 * Adx$. Upon integrating from zero to l, we get strain energy in 1 cube to be $\frac{F^2l}{6AY}$, hence total strain energy in the 2 cubes will be $\frac{F^2l}{3AY}$.

Then force can be found be conserving energies $\frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)v'^2 + \frac{F^2l}{3AY} = \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2$.

This is just something I tried for an elastic collision but I'm not sure whether my assumption of energy conservation is valid, or if there are additional parameters that I did not consider here. Also, how would we extend this to inelastic collision, i.e. is there is a more general approach that can be applied to any kind of collision?

Comment: For inelastic / visco elastic collisions e.g., if a small cube of steel collides with a big cube of soap/butter the impact force would be low. So the properties should enter into picture.

Comment: the usual treatment is to use the conserved quantities to relate the results to the initial conditions, and thus has a sensible zero-collision-time limit, which is then how we usually present the solutions. If you want to study the details of the collision itself, you have to have a model for the springiness of the materials involved, and you can solve the dynamics and then take the time derivative of the rate of transfer of momentum. The roots of that time derivative is where the forces are greatest.